# Private class variables keep resetting between forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Im creating a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game in c# and so far i only have 2 forms.

- `frmMain.` (The main game form)
- `frmPlayerInfo.` (used to select single or 2 player)

I have also created a class Player.

so my though was this. Once the player enters their name, it will go to a properties in the Player class and store the value in the private variable so i can get it on the main form for display purposes.
But when i go back to the main form, the propertie brings back null, Why is this ?

Heres my code.

Player Class... (I have removed irelevant properties and variables not related to this problem)

```
class Player
{
    #region PrivatVariables
    private string _PlayerName1;
    private string _PlayerName2;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string playerName1
    {
        get
        {
            return _PlayerName1;
        }
        set
        {
            _PlayerName1 = value;
        }
    }

    public string playerName2
    {
        get
        {
            return _PlayerName2;
        }
        set
        {
            _PlayerName2 = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion


    public Player()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    internal void resetValues()
    {
    }
}
```

Main Form... (I just included the main code, i call the new game code on form load)

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    Player player = new Player();

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO : Set timer so that form can load first.

        newGame();
    }

    private void newGame()
    {
        // Creating an instance of the Form used to take in player info.
        frm_PlayerInfo playerInfo = new frm_PlayerInfo();
        // This is  going to pop up the player info form.
        DialogResult dialogResult = playerInfo.ShowDialog(); 
        LoadForm();
    }

    private void LoadForm()
    {
        grpBoxPlayer1.Text = player.playerName1;
    }
```

Player Info Form... ()

```
 public partial class frm_PlayerInfo : Form
{
    Player player = new Player();

    bool isAnimated;

    public frm_PlayerInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frm_PlayerInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Setting player tow input visibility to false because there will always be one player.
        this.txtPlayerName2.Visible = false;
        this.lblPlayerName2.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnNext.Visible = false;

        // Used to slide the Form up or down.
        slideAnimation(ref isAnimated);
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Populating the Player Properties
        player.playerName1 = this.txtPlayerName1.Text;


        if (this.txtPlayerName2.Text != "")
        {
            player.playerName2 = this.txtPlayerName2.Text;
        }

        // Calling the animation method to close the animation back up and then the form will be closed.
        slideAnimation(ref isAnimated);
        FadeOutAnimation();
    }
```

Comment: add the code, where you populate the players.

Comment: i think you "Main Form" `player` is not the same as the "Player Info Form" `player`. They are independently. But this is only a presumption. You need to show the code where the player of the "Player Info Form" is declared and initialized.

Comment: Hi guys, please review now after the Edit, 

I am populating the Player properties on the button start click, please review last section of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of the Player class in frmMain, and pass it to frmplayerInfo in the constructor. Right now you don't have a reference to the Player class in frmMain.

in the `newGame()` method:

```
private void newGame()
{
    Player player = new Player();
    // Creating an instance of the Form used to take in player info.
    frm_PlayerInfo playerInfo = new frm_PlayerInfo(player);
    // This is  going to pop up the player info form.
    DialogResult dialogResult = playerInfo.ShowDialog(); 
    LoadForm();
}
```

and in the frm_PlayerInfo class, remove this code row `Player player = new Player();`, and change it's constructor:

```
public partial class frm_PlayerInfo : Form
{
Player player;

public frm_PlayerInfo(Player player)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.player = player;
}
// the rest of the form
```

Another option is to have the player names properties directly in frmPlayerInfo.

Comment: Hi there, I do have an instance of player class in the Main form, its at the top of the code, ill include it now, please review once it is up

Comment: But it's not to the same instance... in frmPlayerInfo you create a new instance of Player, and frmMain does not have access to it.

Comment: I see what you mean, So how do i use the same instance form the main form in the player info form ?

Comment: That's what I wrote in my answer: you create the instance in the first form, and pass it to the second one in it's constructor...

Comment: So would you advice passing the instance as a reference ? Like so...

frm_PlayerInfo playerInfo = new frm_PlayerInfo(ref player);

Comment: @JodyStocks - `ref` doesn't mean what you think it means. There's no need for `ref` here, the code shown in Zohar's answer should be sufficient (although you can remove the `Player player = new Player();` line since we can see that it's constructed elsewhere in `frmMain`.

Comment: Ow my Word, Please do excuse my me, i forgot to scroll up, i was just reading the comments and did not check the answer provided, My apologies

Comment: Another question, how do I use the class instance all over form player info ? I can't use it out side of the constructors, please advice

Comment: Hahahaha, thank you so much, its always the simple ones that get you